# Lambda expressions in VS 2010 as opposed to gcc

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I am trying to compile my code in VS 2010 that compiles and works in gcc, but I get a weird error on a lambda expression:

```
   std::function<double (size_t level, size_t q)> doLevel = [&](size_t level, size_t q)
   {  //line 52
       double thisLevelP = density(q, data[level]);
       if(level==T-1) return thisLevelP;
       if(level==t-1) return  thisLevelP*A(q,state)*doLevel(level+1,state);
       double continuation = 0.0;
       for(size_t i=0; i<Q; ++i)
       {
           continuation += A(q, i)*doLevel(level+1, i);
       }
       return thisLevelP*continuation;
   };
```

The error is:

```
Error   1   error C2086: 'size_t &_T' : redefinition    c:\users\ga1009\documents\phd\cpp\pmi\cpp\test\baumiterationtest.cpp    52
Error   2   error C2661: '`anonymous-namespace'::`anonymous-namespace'::<lambda1>::<lambda1>' : no overloaded function takes 8 arguments    c:\users\ga1009\documents\phd\cpp\pmi\cpp\test\baumiterationtest.cpp    52
```

What is wrong?

Comment: By the way, you have some UB. You need to explicitly specify the return type of the lambda in this case.

Comment: Which line is which line? Indicate that. I don't see any `size_t & _T` in the posted code.

Comment: @Grzenio: Undefined Behavior

Comment: @AndyProwl, what is SSCCE?

Comment: @Grzenio: UB stands for Undefined Behavior!

Comment: @Grzenio: A [Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Looks like VS2010 only supports an older version of lambdas anyways: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Comment: @Nawaz, the line 52 is indicated in the comment. I can't see `size_t & _T` in the code either...

Comment: @AndyProwl, where is the undefined behaviour? I will gladly fix it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, unfortunately I didn't really follow the evolution of the standard. Am I using new features here? How can I transform it to use only the old features?

Comment: @Grzenio, Just add `-> double` after the parameter list. And yes, lambdas are new as of C++11. You'll have to define a separate function for it to work in 03.

Comment: @Grzenio: `[&](size_t level, size_t q) -> double` to explicitly state the return type. And theres' no need to sepcify parameter names in the function type argument: `std::function<double(size_t,size_t)>`

Comment: @chris, it didn't really change anything :(

Comment: It saved you from having the worst time of your life in two months trying to figure out why the program is suddenly not working :)

Comment: @ArneMertz, it didn't change the error message :(

Comment: @chris, ah so you are saying this would cause some UB?

Comment: @Grzenio and what about the SSCCE? Without that, we can just guess.

Comment: @Grzenio, Here's what the standard says: `if the compound-statement is of the form
{ attribute-speciﬁer-seqoptreturn expression ; }
the type of the returned expression after lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1), array-to-pointer conversion (4.2), and function-to-pointer conversion (4.3);
— otherwise, void.` Since your body does not follow that template, it would have a `void` return type on a conforming compiler, and you return a `double`. If it was something like `return 2.5 * 6.5;`, the return type would be implicitly deduced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As seen in the comments above by chris, lambdas with multiple return statements need an explicit return type which can be declared like this `->double`.

More importantly though the offending line is the variable named `t` which is captured by the lambda. I originally though this was a name clash but as STL correctly points out it happens with any two names which are the same except one is capital. This is a compiler bug which is known and has been fixed in the newest versions.

```
double density(std::size_t, int)
{
    return 0;
}
double A(std::size_t, int)
{
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int data[] = {1,2,3};
    std::size_t T = 1;
    std::size_t t = 2;   //<<<<< change this name and it compiles
    std::size_t state = 3;
    std::size_t Q = 4;
    std::function<double (int,int)> doLevel = [&](int level, int q)->double
   { 
       double thisLevelP = density(q, data[level]);
      if(level==T-1) 
           return thisLevelP;
      if(level==t-1) 
           return  thisLevelP*A(q,state)*doLevel(level+1,state);
       double continuation = 0.0;
       for(size_t i=0; i<Q; ++i)
       {
           continuation += A(q, i)*doLevel(level+1, i);
       }
       return thisLevelP*continuation;
   };
}
```

Comment: +1 for creating an SSCCE. The code fails to compile in VS2012 also.

Comment: looks like STL used the wrong name (I mean the guy and the library ;)

Comment: Minimum reproducible example `int main() { unsigned T = 1, t = 1; auto f = [&](){ return T && t; }; }` Fails with `error C2086: 'unsigned int &_T' : redefinition`

Comment: I filed a bug report (my first ever, how exciting)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that! I was struggling to create an SSCCE for the last hour!

Comment: 1. This is a compiler bug, not a library bug.
2. "T" and "t" aren't special. "Foo" and "foo" will trigger it too.
3. This was reported as http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746135/lambda-expression-problem and has been fixed. The fix will be available in VC12 (note: VC9 = VS 2008, VC10 = VS 2010, VC11 = VS 2012).